# Cauchy–Riemann equations and complex differentiability at origin

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

Consider the function defined by

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }\operatorname{Re}(z)=0\vee\operatorname{Im}(z)=0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

I would like to show that the real and imaginary parts of $f$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at the origin but am not sure if just saying $0=0$ and $0=-0$ is enough or not also is $f$ complex differentiable at the origin, I am not sure on how to show whether it is or not, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are right. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{u(h,0)-u(0,0)}h=\lim_{h\to0}0=0$. By the same kind of argument, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. Since $0=0$ and $0=-0$…

Note that $f$ *not* differentiable at the origin, since it's not even continuous there.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! :)

Comment: Thank you for confirming that 0=0 and 0=-0 is enough evidence, you mention it is not continuous there, how would you prove that? I have gotten as far as looking for a contradiction in: for all epsilon>0, there exists a delta such that |f-L| < epsilon whenever 0<|f-L|<delta

Comment: @Complexicity $\lim_{x\to0}f(x+xi)=1\neq0=f(0)$.